# Creates a temporary which is freed while still in use

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm creating a small application that explores variable lifetimes and threads. I want to load in a file once, and then use its contents (in this case an audio file) in a separate channel. I am having issues with value lifetimes.

I'm almost certain the syntax is wrong for what I have so far (for creating a static variable), but I can't find any resources for `File` types and lifetimes. What I have thus far produces this error:

```
let file = &File::open("src/censor-beep-01.wav").unwrap();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
 let x: &'static File = file;
               ------------- type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

The code I currently have is:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
#![allow(unused_imports)]
#![allow(unused_must_use)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, stdin, Read};
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, TryRecvError};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::fs::File;
use std::rc::Rc;
use rodio::Source;

fn main() {
    let file = &File::open("src/censor-beep-01.wav").unwrap();
    let x: &'static File = file;
        loop {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let tmp = x;
            let (stream, stream_handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
            let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(tmp)).unwrap();
            stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                    break;
                }
                Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
                    println!("z");
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
                }
            }
        });

        let mut line = String::new();
        let stdin = io::stdin();
        let _ = stdin.lock().read_line(&mut line);
        let _ = tx.send(());
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the file with `Arc` and `Mutex` like `Arc::new(Mutex::new(file))` and then clone the file before passing it to the thread.

`Arc` is used for reference counting, which is needed to share the target object (in your case it is a file) across the thread and `Mutex` is needed to access the target object synchronously.

sample code (I have simplified your code to make it more understandable):

```
let file = Arc::new(Mutex::new(File::open("src/censor-beep-01.wav").unwrap()));
    loop {
        let file = file.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let mut file_guard = match file.lock() {
                Ok(guard) => guard,
                Err(poison) => poison.into_inner()
            };
            let file = file_guard.deref();
            // now you can pass above file object to BufReader like "BufReader::new(file)"
        });
    }
```

reason for `creates a temporary which is freed while still in use` error:
You have only stored the reference of the file without the actual file object. so, the object will be droped in that line itself.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful! Mind telling me the purpose of the code within the thread scope? I've used this with the lines that play the file on every iteration of the thread, but am getting a fair few `the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<usize, std::io::Error>` errors

Comment: Sure! One of the rust's guarantee is concurrency safety. So, rust won't allow non-sync object to share across thread. By using mutex we have made the file object sync. In order to access the file that is wrapped with mutex, we have to acquire lock. That is the code you are seeing inside the thread scope. Regarding error it will easy for me if you shared the code that you are trying using pastebin 

Comment: Hi! Thanks for explanation - here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.pl/view/d1f04a4a

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman got it, I have edited the answer to satisfy your use-case. give it a try!

Comment: @fellinlovewithaman is the solution worked for you?

Comment: Hey man, sorry - was caught up with work. Unfortunately no, `file.lock()` and `file_guard.deref()` are having lifetime issues too - they don't live long enough. Cheers